# React Js Time Selector

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I have a component like this

[image: Select time Component]

I want to select the year from the first one, quarter second, and month in 3, but when I select a year and try to select a quarter the year disappears.

```
> code for year Selector

<DatePicker
            selected={values.year}
            onChange={(date) => setValues({ year: date })}
            showYearPicker
            dateFormat="yyyy"
            yearItemNumber={9}
            className="inputDate"
          />
 
       

> code for quarter Selector

          <DatePicker
            name="quarter"
            onChange={(date) => setValues({ quarter: date })}
            selected={values.quarter}
            dateFormat="QQQ"
            showQuarterYearPicker
            className="inputDate"
            onSelect={(date) => {
              moment().endOf("quarter");
            }}
          />
     

> code for Month Selector

          <ButtonGroup className="button-container">
            <Button
              variant="outline-primary"
              size="md"
              className="month-button"
              onClick={() =>
                setValues({
                  month: moment()
                    .month(showMonth(values.quarter) - 3)
                    .format("MMMM YYYY"),
                })
              }
            >
              {moment()
                .month(showMonth(values.quarter) - 3)
                .format("MMMM")}
            </Button>
```

here I have my date object

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
year: new Date(),
quarter: new Date(),
month: "",
});
```

It's okay like this or should use a different state for every component.

I want to select a specific date from every component

Comment: Please share some code! Without code what can we do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to change the state with `setValues`, you're clearing your component's previous state in the code. You should keep previous one and change current state. It can be done with [Object Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So change
`setValues` in components as below:

```
 <DatePicker
        selected={values.year}
        onChange={(date) => setValues({ ...values , year: date })}
        showYearPicker
        dateFormat="yyyy"
        yearItemNumber={9}
        className="inputDate"
      />
<DatePicker
        name="quarter"
        onChange={(date) => setValues({ ...values, quarter: date })}
        selected={values.quarter}
        dateFormat="QQQ"
        showQuarterYearPicker
        className="inputDate"
        onSelect={(date) => {
          moment().endOf("quarter");
        }}
      />
<ButtonGroup className="button-container">
        <Button
          variant="outline-primary"
          size="md"
          className="month-button"
          onClick={() =>
            setValues({
              ...values,
              month: moment()
                .month(showMonth(values.quarter) - 3)
                .format("MMMM YYYY"),
            })
          }
        >
          {moment()
            .month(showMonth(values.quarter) - 3)
            .format("MMMM")}
        </Button>
```